# Merge into one row from two rows? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

If I have code for example

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    table1.column2, table2.column3, table2.column4 
FROM 
    table1
JOIN
    table2 ON table1.column = table2.column
WHERE 
    table1.column1 IN ('Value1', 'Value2')
```

This will return two rows of the same data, except each one will have one value that is different for a specific column. How can I bring the one value over and just have it result in one column?

for example it would currently result in something like this:

```
column1       column2        column3
Value1        Value2         Value3
Value1        Value2         Value5
```

Basically it creates two rows because in column 3, the  values are different, is there any way I can bring that value 5 and make a separate column for it into the first row?

Would this involve pivoting or how could I go about in doing this?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your results don't make sense.  Your query is for two columns, but your results have three.

Comment: what if you have 3 different value in `column3` ? How do you want this to be ?

Comment: Let's just say in column 3 there can only be 2 different values only. I pretty much want that second value to be a part of the first row instead of having a separate row going forward with the rest of the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since column3 only have 2 value, MIN() and MAX() will gives you both the value

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2, MIN(table2.column3) , MAX(table2.column3)
FROM   table1
JOIN   table2 
ON     table1.column = table2.column
WHERE  table1.column1 IN ('Value1', 'Value2')
GROUP BY table1.column2, table2.column3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the column depending in what you want. it could be either - `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, `AVG`, etc..

```
SELECT  table1.column1, table1.column2, MAX(table2.column3) AS column3
FROM    table1
        INNER JOIN table2 
            ON table1.column = table2.column
WHERE   table1.column1 IN ('Value1', 'Value2')
GROUP   BY table1.column1, table1.column2
```

Answer (score 1):

`LAG()` could get the row just before the current row. So the script something like this:

```
    select * from(
     SELECT DISTINCT table1.column2, table2.column3, table2.column4,lag(column4) over (order by table1.column2,table2.column3,table2.column4) l
     FROM table1
     JOIN
     table2 on 
     table1.column = table2.column
     WHERE table1.column1 IN ('Value1', 'Value2')
   )t where t.l is not null
```